# Any way to find download and upload rate though batch on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

We have a Windows bat script to calculate download rate through `ping` command:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set address=8.8.8.8
set packagesize=65500
set times=20
set accumulator=0

for /l %%a in (1,1,%times%) do (
    for /f %%b in ('getms ping -n 1 -l %packagesize% %address%') do (
        set /a "accumulator=!accumulator!+%%b"
    )
)

set /v "velocity=!packagesize!*!times!/!accumulator!"
echo.!velocity!kbps
```

where `getms` is another bat that uses a lot of `for` commands to separate the millisecond value returned by `ping` (that varies according to language).

Edited:
Well, since that calculated bandwidth is not related with real bandwidth, once `ping` is related with latency, not transfer speed, how can I edit that script to match the correct download rate? Any way to do that with native commands, not 3rd party ones?

Comment: Ping measures latency, not transfer speed.

Comment: As pointed out, you can have a high latency, and have a high transfer speed.  You will be unable to use ping to determine your download speed.  Even if you could use ping to determine your download speed, it wouldn't be applicable, to upload speed.

Comment: Latency does have a big impact on the maximum download speed but the result of that calculation will not be very accurate. Also no matter how small your ping, the speed can never go above your actual connection speed. There are [many sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=latency+tcp+throughput) that explain this topic in detail.

Comment: Ok, edited to turn it utile.

Comment: "how can I edit that script to match the correct download rate?" - You can't with bash, the way you would with an actual programming language, is first determine the size of the file being downloaded then every second compare the file that is being downloaded to that size.  By knowing what the current size of the local file is you can determine how quickly you are downloading the file

Comment: By "utile" do you mean "utility" by chance?

Comment: Sorry by my poor Engish ^^

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Do you just want to measure the speed of your internet connection?

Comment: Only to apply script on GPO to install a 150MB software in all computers (about 2000) in a high traffic network (30Mbps for all of them). If traffic is low, download transfer speed is high and script will allow software copy. If traffic is high, download transfer speed is low and script will deny software copy. Later, when a lot of computers will have that software copied and installed, we will perform the copy to others without that traffic analysis.

Comment: Most of the time you link GPO's to OU's, but you can also link them to AD Site objects. If you linked the GPO to the AD Site objects of your well connected subnets that should meet your needs here.

Comment: Oh, so it's a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029). You want to do X (download software only if network isn't saturated), but you're asking how to do Y (measure transfer speed with `ping) which is completely unrelated to X.

Comment: Yeah. But I asked for Y solution. Someone asked me what is Y purpose, so I explaned what are my real needs, X. I would like to know both solution, for X and Y. I think X answer is more interesting, but to obey Superuser rules I decided to do a more concrete question, Y...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service) to download your software package. It is designed to only use idle network bandwidth, so it will download slowly in case the machine is already downloading something.

Then you can wait a bit and monitor download progress. If it is too slow, you can either suspend or cancel your download. If it is OK, just let it complete.

Easiest way to invoke BITS is PowerShell. Here is some code to get you started:

```powershell
$transfer = Start-BitsTransfer -Asynchronous -Source 'http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu-releases/17.04/ubuntu-17.04-server-i386.iso' -Destination 'c:\Temp'
$bytesTransferred = 0
while($transfer.JobState -eq 'Connecting' -or $transfer.JobState -eq 'Transferring')
{
    $delay = 5
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $delay

    if ($transfer.JobState -eq 'Transferring')
    {
        $bytesDelta = $transfer.BytesTransferred - $bytesTransferred
        $bytesTransferred = $transfer.BytesTransferred

        # Check if speed is less than 1 MB/s
        if ($bytesDelta -lt (1MB * $delay))
        {
            Write-Warning 'Download is too slow, aborting'
            Remove-BitsTransfer $transfer
            # Also can use Suspend-BitsTransfer $transfer to pause and Resume-BitsTransfer $transfer to resume
            break
        }
    }
}
if ($transfer.JobState -eq 'Transferred')
{
    Complete-BitsTransfer $transfer
    Write-Information 'Download complete'
}
else
{
    Write-Error "Download error $($transfer.ErrorDescription)"    
}
```

Save the script with `ps1` extension and use `PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File YourScript.ps1` to call it from batch file (or just call it directly).

Comment: Hahaha. It answers my final needs. Perhaps I would change question to match that answer :)